# Ajax Website, problems with History and Seo

Tags: ajax, url, web, seo, history

I have a few problems i could use some input on.

I have a website, where all the content is loaded with ajax, it works quite well. There are a few issues with that approach though, or some UX issues.

- User cannot copy URL from loaded content, since it will allways show the default URL only.
- SEO will take a hit, since it cannot be crawled, the sitemap is like 2 pages only, even though when a normal user browses, they will see alot more.
- Browser history, back and forward, does not work. Hitting the back button goes to the main page.

Now, i have searched and read alot. 
Google has a hack, that seems to allow the site to be crawled, IF you use # in your url, does not work with empty url, which leads me to...

Manipulating the browser history with pushState/popState.

Now, i have tried getting it to work, but i just cant get my head around which process is the best way to take. Should i redo all my ajax?

Right now i have 2 div boxes, and i switch between them with loaded content, to get that nice sweet transition between pages. My frontpage is basically just 2 empty divs, nothing else. It works, but i get the feeling it is a pretty bad way to do it, thoughts?

If anyone know some good guides, feel free to give me, i have as i said read alot, but i might have missed some golden ones out there.

Answer (score 1):

Google does execute some Javascript when indexing and ranking pages. However, text which is not immediately visible to users is demoted when establishing content relevancy.

> Manipulating the browser history with pushState/popState.

It is very unlikely Google will trust your content if you need to use those tricks. And content which is not trusted is not ranked.

**UPDATE:** Manipulating browser history with pushState is ok.

Moreover, if your URLs change all the time, Google won't appreciate it, unless you manage to set canonical links.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is actually the first time i hear that the new html pushState can be bad. I guess i need to do some more digging.

I still am not sure how i should proceed then, what would you do, remake the whole code? Normally i just make the good old normal websites with pretty url and php autoloader, but i do indeed enjoy ajax websites, it gives a much more smooth interactive UX.

Comment: I would use the Fetch as Google feature of Google Webmaster Tool to get an idea of how Google perceives your pages. It will give you an idea of what works or not.

Comment: I have, it works fine, and Google just show my main page, it doesnt crawl my ajax.

It works, its ok, but i know it is not SEO friendly, and i have noticed people using backspace, which will make them "refresh" the site, and go to the frontpage.

I feel i need a proper way to control their history, back and forth, and while im at it, also do some proper SEO'ing.

Comment: I would like to retract, using pushState is not going to get Goggle frowning. Sorry for that.

Comment: Sounds good. I ended up going down that route. Which did work out pretty good, except for a few annoying quirks! Thanks again.